# Coding Pattern for use instance member

Tags: java, design-patterns

Suppose I have a class called `CommandLineOperation`. This class accesses API resources. Thus I have defined one instance member of type `APIAccessor`.

```
class CommandLineOperation {
    APIAccessor apiAccessor;
    void create() {
        apiAccessor = new APIAccessor(email,password);
        //do work for creation
    }
    void update() {
        apiAccessor = new APIAccessor(email,password);
        //do work for update
    }
}

class APIAccessor {
    String email;
    String password;
    APIAccessor(email,password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

The operations in CommandLine, are infrequent, is it a better approach to instantiate `APIAccessor` under every operations or create once using constructor of `CommandLineOperation` class. e.g.

```
CommandLineOperation(String email,String password) {
    this.apiAccessor = new APIAccessor(email,password);
}
```

Please let me know or suggest good coding design pattern. Or suggest any reference book so that I can improve my coding standard based on the analysis. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does every operation need an `APIAccessor`?

Comment: @Flown yes, every operation will use it

Comment: Are there many implementation of `APIAccessor` or only one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer is: it *depends* - on your context/requirements.

Advantages of creating an ApiAccessor once when creating a CommandLineOperation instance:

- you can create **immutable** objects then (by making that field final). That has various advantages - as you *always* know that this field is initialized (ideally, you might even want to validate that the ApiAccessor is actually valid and not containing wrong information)
- your other methods can *focus* on their direct responsibility - instead of worrying if that field has already been initialized
- as a consequence, unit testing is also easier - in case you need mocking, you only have to provide an ApiAccessor object **once** - instead of dealing with it each time you invoke one of the "real" methods of CommandLineOperation

Disadvantages:

- you can't "switch" the ApiAccessor for a given CommandLineOperation object
- in case you have millions and millions of these objects hanging around without being your, you waste some memory

But when you think about it: those disadvantages aren't much of an issue in the real world anyway.

Regarding the comments that the required credentials come from parsing files: that boils down to dependency injection!

Meaning: the CommandLineOperation class should **not** contain code to construct an ApiAccessor instance. That object should either be injected (via a dependency injection framework) - or provided via the constructor for example.

Comment: are you referring to DI when you say "creating an ApiAccessor upon creation"?

Comment: @GhostCat i understand this part. Now if this email and password will be supplied from a configuration file, then is it better approach?? because i am thinking about coupling. as I have another class called `ConfigurationFileLoader` that will load config file and assign it into properties instance. I am reading the Properties for email and password. So file loader will also be a part of code.

Comment: @GhostCat so you mean to say `ConfigurationFileLoader` instance should be part of or instantiated in `AdminAPIAccessor` and with in `CommandLineOperation`, i have to pass instance of `AdminAPIAccessor` into the constructor right??

Comment: You pass an `ApiAccessor` to the `CommandLineOperation` constructor for example.